# Selenium get get xpath from element loop return same result

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

This is my python code , find all elements and process each element, but im have problem , output code is same result, but if i print out element html, nothing wrong with my html element,

```
xpath_chatlist = '//div[@class="content-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]'
xpath_chatlist_name = '//div[@class="listTextName"]/h3'
xpath_chatlist_msg = '//div[@class="listTextChat"]'
xpath_chatlist_date = '//div[@class="listTime"]'
xpath_chatlist_total = '//div[@class="listInfoBottom"]/span'

print('=============START=============')
chatlist = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@aria-label="ChatListItem"]')
for item in chatlist:
    print('innerHTML : '+item.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
    print('Name : '+item.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_chatlist_name).text)
    print('Msg : '+item.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_chatlist_msg).text)
    print('Date : '+item.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_chatlist_date).text)
    print('Total : '+item.find_element(By.XPATH, xpath_chatlist_total).text)
print('=============END=============')
```

This is my output

```
=============START=============
innerHTML : <div class="listItemWrapper"><div class="css-1ixlgd5"><img src="https://website.com/image/v1/u/23034869/user_thumbnail/mobile" alt="Anas"></div><div class="css-1yssxig"><div class="listTextName"><h3 class="unreads">Anas</h3></div><div class="wrapperText"><div class="listTextChat">Terima kasih!</div></div></div><div class="css-up9rb4"><div class="listTime">06:46</div><div class="listInfoBottom"><span class="css-818igq">1</span><div class="listOption"><div class="css-1w7t4hv" aria-label="ChatListMenu"></div><div class="css-3ybd2c"><ul><li>Tempel Chat</li><li>Atur Penerimaan Chat</li><li>Laporkan Pengguna</li><li>Tandai Sudah Dibaca</li><li>Hapus</li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>
Name : Anas
Msg : Terima kasih!
Date : 06:46
Total : 1
innerHTML : <div class="listItemWrapper"><div class="css-1ixlgd5"><img src="https://website.com/image/v1/u/1581313/user_thumbnail/mobile" alt="Dewi"></div><div class="css-1yssxig"><div class="listTextName"><h3 class="unreads">Dewi</h3></div><div class="wrapperText"><div class="listTextChat">Hai, barang ini ready ga?</div></div></div><div class="css-up9rb4"><div class="listTime">7 Okt</div><div class="listInfoBottom"><span class="css-818igq">2</span><div class="listOption"><div class="css-1w7t4hv" aria-label="ChatListMenu"></div><div class="css-3ybd2c"><ul><li>Tempel Chat</li><li>Atur Penerimaan Chat</li><li>Laporkan Pengguna</li><li>Tandai Sudah Dibaca</li><li>Hapus</li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>
Name : Anas
Msg : Terima kasih!
Date : 06:46
Total : 1
=============END=============
```

Expected result :

```
=============START=============
innerHTML : <div class="listItemWrapper"><div class="css-1ixlgd5"><img src="https://website.com/image/v1/u/23034869/user_thumbnail/mobile" alt="Anas"></div><div class="css-1yssxig"><div class="listTextName"><h3 class="unreads">Anas</h3></div><div class="wrapperText"><div class="listTextChat">Terima kasih!</div></div></div><div class="css-up9rb4"><div class="listTime">06:46</div><div class="listInfoBottom"><span class="css-818igq">1</span><div class="listOption"><div class="css-1w7t4hv" aria-label="ChatListMenu"></div><div class="css-3ybd2c"><ul><li>Tempel Chat</li><li>Atur Penerimaan Chat</li><li>Laporkan Pengguna</li><li>Tandai Sudah Dibaca</li><li>Hapus</li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>
Name : Anas
Msg : Terima kasih!
Date : 06:46
Total : 1
innerHTML : <div class="listItemWrapper"><div class="css-1ixlgd5"><img src="https://website.com/image/v1/u/1581313/user_thumbnail/mobile" alt="Dewi"></div><div class="css-1yssxig"><div class="listTextName"><h3 class="unreads">Dewi</h3></div><div class="wrapperText"><div class="listTextChat">Hai, barang ini ready ga?</div></div></div><div class="css-up9rb4"><div class="listTime">7 Okt</div><div class="listInfoBottom"><span class="css-818igq">2</span><div class="listOption"><div class="css-1w7t4hv" aria-label="ChatListMenu"></div><div class="css-3ybd2c"><ul><li>Tempel Chat</li><li>Atur Penerimaan Chat</li><li>Laporkan Pengguna</li><li>Tandai Sudah Dibaca</li><li>Hapus</li></ul></div></div></div></div></div>
Name : Dewi
Msg : Hai, barang ini ready ga?
Date : 7 Okt
Total : 1
=============END=============
```

Whats wrong with my code, any help would be apreciated, thanks

EDIT :

Solved with access loop index

```
i=1;
for item in chatlist:
    x=str(i)
    print(self.Tampilkan('Name : '+item.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[@aria-label="ChatListItem"]['+x+']//div[@class="listTextName"]/h3').text))
    i += 1
```

but im still dont know why cannot find xpath in loop using item element, if somebody know please give the reason

Comment: An `xpath` is going to reference only a single element on the entire page.  You are literally telling the code to find item by the same `xpath` every time in your loop, so you'll be getting back the same tag each time.

Comment: @Chris but each loops `item` is different

Comment: @Chris is right, xPath are bidirectional. Your list of items is different, but your nested search will find the first element from the DOM not from the ```item``` html. Use cssSelector instead

Answer (score 0):

you're close. you want the xpath relative to the "item":

```
xpath_chatlist = './/div[@class="content-container"]/div/div/div[1]/div[3]'
xpath_chatlist_name = './/div[@class="listTextName"]/h3'
xpath_chatlist_msg = './/div[@class="listTextChat"]'
xpath_chatlist_date = './/div[@class="listTime"]'
xpath_chatlist_total = './/div[@class="listInfoBottom"]/span'
```